# Error "No Kerberos credentials available" al pasar servidor de correo lotus a exchange

Tags: php, imap

Tengo una web que se conecta al servidor de correo por `imap` para descargar los mensajes y procesar automáticamente el trabajo dependiendo del asunto, pero tras pasar de lotus a exchange ha dejado de funcionar con este mensaje en el log de error del apache:

> Unknown: Kerberos error: No Kerberos credentials available (try running kinit) for xxxxxx

Y en google encontré la solución aquí:

http://forums.kayako.com/threads/fix-kerberos-error-on-email-parser.29626/

Pero no consigo arreglar el problema. ¿Alguien sabe por qué?

Comment: Presupongo que hablas de PHP, ¿qué sistema operativo usas y qué versión de PHP? ¿Cuando hablas de microsoft te refieres a exchange?

Comment: Ubuntu server y php 5.5.9 y Microsoft exchange

Comment: Bien, Ubuntu 14.04. ¿Podrías poner la línea en la que usas el `imap_open`?

Comment: $mbox = imap_open($mb, $user, $passwd);

Comment: ¿Y el contenido de $mb? Creo que el problema no está ahí, si no que por algún motivo no te conecta con los nuevos parámetros y más adelante tu PHP provoca un error (que se estará también en el log de apache) que es el que provoca la página en blanco. ¿Podrías mirar qué otros mensajes hay en el log de error aunque supuestamente no estén relacionados con imap?

Comment: Estoy visitando de nuevo el enlace que pones. ¿Qué has hecho de lo que aparece ahí y qué te ocurre al terminar los pasos? Si mi respuesta te solucionó el problema no olvides marcarla como correcta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guiándome por el enlace que facilitas, para averiguar cuál podría ser el problema, veo que podría estar relacionado con la librería segura que usa la extensión `imap` de PHP en Ubuntu para conectar al servidor Exchange.

Este problema [fue solucionado en PHP 5.3.2](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3_2/ext/imap/php_imap.c?r1=294109&r2=294108&pathrev=294109), por lo que ya no es necesario recompilar la extensión `imap` de PHP, basta con agregar una opción `DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR` para deshabilitar el intercambio de credenciales a través de `GSSAPI` (`kerberos` por norma general).

Prueba a modificar la forma en la que te conectas al servidor agregando los parámetros indicados anteriormente a la llamada que haces a `imap_open()`:

```
$mbox = imap_open(
  $mb,
  $user,
  $passwd,
  null,
  null,
  [
    'DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => [
      'GSSAPI',
    ],
  ]
);
```

Comment: sigue la pagina en blanco y ahora el log de apache lanza PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')'

Comment: ¿Podrías revisar el código que has copiado? Es probable que al pegar hayas sobreescrito algo de tu código.

Comment: si! eso era! gracias!! ya se ha ido la pagina en blanco y se ve la web aunque no descarga los mensajes nuevos

Comment: ¿Te sale algo en el log? ¿Compruebas que la conexión al servidor se ha establecido correctamente? ¿Podrías poner el código que le sigue al `imap_open`?

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el contenido de `$mb` o comprobar que el nombre del buzón es correcto? Por defecto es `INBOX`, aunque podrían haberlo cambiado, consulta con el administrador del servidor de correo.

Comment: si perdona, era eso. en lotus era diferente y al cambiarlo a inbox ha descargado los mensajes nuevos. gracias!

Comment: Me alegra que se solucionara :) Tal y como te dije en el comentario anterior, si te ayudó a resolver tu problema marca la respuesta como correcta, gracias :)

Comment: no me sale la opción, como lo hago?

Comment: En el lateral izquierdo de mi respuesta hay apartado que contiene un botón (⇑) para votar positivamente mi respuesta (te lo agradecería si tienes el detalle), un número (0 por ahora, si me das un voto subiría a uno, etc), y un botón para dar un voto negativo (⇓). Bajo él los autores de la pregunta ven un icono adicional que es una marca de correcto (✓). Pulsando en él se pondrá en verde indicando que has marcado mi respuesta como correcta :)

Comment: muchísimas gracias de nuevo, me estoy peleando con este problema hace días y no veía salida. he hecho lo que has dicho pero no puedo darte el voto positivo, tampoco negativo, se pone y se quita y me dice que no puedo

Comment: Conforme vayas haciendo más preguntas, respondiendo otras y obteniendo más votos positivos de los demás conseguirás reputación con la que podrás desbloquear ciertas opciones, como votar positiva o negativamente otras preguntas y respuestas, etc. Suerte y bienvenido a la comunidad :)